# getAudioInputStream cannot read mp3 java

Tags: java

```
AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileAudio);     

AudioFormat audFormat = in.getFormat();

audFormat = new AudioFormat(
                        AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 
                        audFormat.getSampleRate(),
                        16, 
                        audFormat.getChannels(),  
                        audFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                        audFormat.getSampleRate(), 
                        false);

din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audFormat, in);
```

thats the code for me trying to get the raw data, however it is throwing the error: could not get audio input stream from input file. This seems to be the case for mp3s only (only tested on wavs and mp3's). ive added mp3plugin and mp3spi, as others have suggested. Also it seems to work on when getting a file from a JFileChooser, however when hard coding the file it falls over.

code for me creating the file:

```
private final String sFolderPath = "C:\\Users\\michael\\Music\\MUSIC\\Bushido.mp3";

File fileAudio = new File(sFolderPath);
```

Comment: Place the `mp3spi.jar` (and it's dependencies `jl*.jar` and `tritonus_share.jar`) in the `ext` directory of your JRE, `{JRE path}/lib/ext`

Comment: i just missed adding the tritonus_share.jar, thanks for the help